# probability and applied statistics

Tags: probability

three companies are bidding on a contract . the relative qualities of the companies are such that company A is twice as good as company B and company B is three times as good as company . what is the probability of each company winning the contract ?

Comment: There's not enough information here. What process determines which company wins the contract? Why doesn't the best company always win?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Assuming that a how good a company is, is precisely it's probability of winning the contract (as it is mentioned in the comments), then we have that $$P(A)=2P(B)$$ and $$P(B)=3P(C)$$ and $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$$ Thus $$P(A)=2(3P(C))=6P(C)$$ which gives $$6P(C)+3P(C)+P(C)=1$$

Comment: So you are assuming that how "good" a company is is precisely it's probability of winning the contract?

Comment: @AlexBecker Yes, since the OP does not give much information, I had to guess. This is the simplest way. Anyway, I do not think that this post will remain open for very long... so, if you think I should delete my answer, I am ok doing it

Comment: No, not at all. But you should probably mention this assumption in the answer.

Comment: @AlexBecker Ok, I did, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is ill-posed.  What does "twice as good" mean?   In the real world of aerospace subcontracting, we engineers evaluate proposals on a "goodness" scoring system that computes a weighted sum of the quality of each solicitation point.  Usually the top scoring proposals are very tightly grouped, never differing by a factor of 2.  So, without further clarification, this is not truly a math problem.